# Generating a new type at every instantiation in C++17

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming, constexpr, c++17

Consider the following code:

```
template <class /* Weird Hack Here */>
struct object
{
    constexpr object(int value, /* Other Weird Hack */) noexcept;
};

int main() 
{
    object foo(1);
    object bar(1);
}
```

Would it be possible using weird tricks in C++17 to have `foo` and `bar` be different types?

Comment: So if I put `object x(1);` inside a loop, do you expect an unbounded number of different types?

Comment: Something similar to this is likely possible due to [stateful metaprogramming](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44267673/1896169), but will be prohibited in the future

Comment: Not C++17, but the metaclasses proposal would give you strong typedefs, which accomplishes nearly the same thing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Real answer: No. If you want different types, write different types. The entire concept is insane.

---

Toy answer, sure. For one, you could macro out the type:

```
template <int N>
struct object {
    object(int ) { }
};

#define object object<__LINE__>
```

Or, since we're being cheeky, you could macro out both names `foo` and `bar`:

```
template <int N>
struct object {
    object(int ) { }
};

#define foo(x) <0> foo(x)
#define bar(x) <1> bar(x)
```

Or, maybe just one of them:

```
template <class T>
struct object {
    object(T ) { }
};

#define foo(x) <double> foo(x)
```

Or, you could use [stateful metaprogramming](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44267673/2069064) to hack into different values. This works on [gcc](https://wandbox.org/permlink/lUgscbl5uEeS6zCc) but not on clang:

```
template <int N>
struct flag
{
    friend constexpr int adl_flag(flag<N>);
    constexpr operator int() { return N; }
};

template <int N>
struct write
{
    friend constexpr int adl_flag(flag<N>) { return N; }
    static constexpr int value = N;
};

template <int N, int = adl_flag(flag<N>{})>
constexpr int read(int, flag<N>, int R = read(0, flag<N + 1>{}))
{
    return R;
}

template <int N>
constexpr int read(float, flag<N>)
{
    return N;
}

template <class T, int N=0, int R=write<read(0, flag<0>{})+N>::value>
struct object {
    object(T ) { }
};
```