# Dynamically build typelist in C++

Tags: c++, types, template-meta-programming

I am looking for a way to dynamically build a type list at compile time. I am creating components holding different types and under the hood I'd like to build a type list that holds all the types registered as components. Imagine the following:

```
using Name = Component<std::string>;
using Position = Component<Vec2f>;
```

I'd then like to be able to end up with a type list which holds `std::string` and `Vec2f` in this case that I can access and expand, i.e. something like this:

```
using AllComponents = SomeMagicTypeThatHoldsAllComponents;
```

I build the typelist portion already and it works something like this:

```
using List = typename MakeTypeList<int, double, std::string>::List;
```

You can append or prepend a type to `List` like this:

```
using Append = typename AppendType<List, float>::List;
using Prepend = typename PrependType<List, Vec2f>::List;
```

And get types by index like this (which basically allows you to expand the types with the help of `std::integer_sequence`):

```
using FirstType = typename TypeAt<List, 0>::Type;
```

The issue I can't wrap my head around is **how to dynamically build this list in the background without breaking the simple Component API**. Does anybody have suggestions if or how this could be achieved?

**EDIT:**
To Clarify, the only solution I could come up with for now is to pass the type list along as an extra template argument, i.e.

```
using AllTypes = using MakeTypeList<>::List;
using Name = Component<AllTypes, std::string>;
using Position = Component<AllTypes, Vec2f>;
```

I am interested in a solution where I don't have to pass the typelist along.

Thank you!

Comment: Are you looking for `std::tuple`?

Comment: No, that's not what I am looking for. If you look at my question, you can see that I allready have the typelist aspects working, my question is how to build it in the background without breaking the Component API.

Comment: @moka I do not understand the question. By dynamically build this list, do you mean at runtime? What do you mean by "in the background"? What do you mean by "breaking the simple Component API"? What have you tried that breaks it and how does it break?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I want to accumulate all the types that were created using the Component<> template into a typelist automatically without breaking the existing API (that's what I meant with "in the background", I don't want you to have to explicitly build the typelist). Hope that makes more sense! I have a feeling that is not possible but I am throwing it out there to see if anybody has an idea.

Comment: @moka That makes sense to me. Unfortunately, that is not supported by c++. You can't know at compile time all of the concrete instances of a template that will exist. One way of looking at it is that you can never know that no other translation unit will define a new one down the line. Perhaps there is a platform specific solution, or one that uses external tools, but this can't be done in standard c++.

Comment: @moka: I think that would require some degree of reflection. I don't think there's a way to do it otherwise without breaking your existing API.

Comment: Okay, thanks everybody, thats what I though. I kinda hoped there was a way :/

Comment: At the moment, no idea how to solve your problem but... do you accept solution with old c-style (and evil) macros?

Comment: I don't really think that I will end up using any macro based solutions, but I think they certainly deserve to be explored here! @HolyBlackCat the solution I had in mind really should list all template instantiations of Component<> if that makes sense.

Comment: Are all `using Blah = Component<Blah>;` lines located in one place?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat No, that's kind of the issue I am trying to overcome, they can be spread out and sit in different namespaces.

Comment: Then I'm taking my words on macro solutions back, they probably won't work.

Comment: Under the hood of [Google Test](https://github.com/google/googletest) there seems to be a macro solution for exactly that kind of problem: Spread across different translation units one may type `TEST(SomeClass, Works) { EXPECT_EQ(SomeClass{}.calc(), 42); }`. Then in the `main` one can `::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv); return RUN_ALL_TESTS();` which magically knows all tests.

Comment: Probably one could come up with a ["not-yet-ill-formed"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44267673/is-stateful-metaprogramming-ill-formed-yet) solution based on stateful metraprogramming (["constexpr counter"](http://b.atch.se/posts/constexpr-counter/)), but you are probably interested in a useful solution to a real problem rather than the answer to the question "is it possible accepting all evil things"?

Comment: @Julius yes, I am rather interested in a useful solution but this is a good mind bender :). I am pretty sure its not worth the trouble at this point and that I might just have to build the typelist from hand.

Comment: What about composition? You can use ADL as in `make_tuple`, but overload the operators of your choice to combine these types, e.g. `container(1)+container(2.0f)+container(3.0d)` = `Container<int, float, double>{1, 2.0f, 3.0d}` via `container(T) -> Container<T>` and `Container<S...>::operator+(Container<T...>) -> Container<S..., T...>`. Furthermore, you can "zip", "cross-multiply", "splice", etc. with other operators/methods. If you don't want to explicitly type, then you want to implicitly type, and ADL in general can get you there.

Comment: To make this a bit more expressive, you can use other tags to infix operations: `container(1) + cross{} + (container(2.0f) + container(3.0d))` = `Cross<Container<int>>{{1}} + Container<float, double>{2.0f, 3.0d}` = `Cross<Container<int>, Container<float, double>>{{1}, {2.0f, 3.0d}}` = `Container<Container<int, float>, Container<int, double>>{{1, 2.0f}, {1, 3.0d}}`. Am I making sense? I'm not 100% sure I understood you, but I suggest looking at Traits/Concepts for ideas. Explicit instantiation has its uses, but no one should expect you (or vice versa) to use it exclusively.

Comment: @JohnP I don't think that will work in this case as there is no way to keep track of the overall list of types as Françoise correctly noted in one of the comments above. The problem is not building type lists in general, but being able to store and modify that list somehow without having to pass it along manually.