# what is the order of the function template instantiation,substitution and overload resolution

Tags: c++, templates

```cpp
#include <iostream>
template<typename T>
void test(T,typename T::type){  //#1
}
template<typename T,typename U>
void test(T,U){  //#2
}
int main(){
  test(0,0); //we know #2 is called
}
```

consider above code,to call function `test` for arguments `0,0`,the complier need to find the best match overload for these arguments and instantiate the function template,firstly,there are two function template named `test`,the complier deduce the template paraments from  arguments for them. I want to know the instantiation or the substitution which is first performanced on the function template in the next step?whether the overload resolution is performanced after them?

[when to instantiate function template](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLTBW_2.4.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r4.cbclx01/overloading_function_templates.htm)

> *If you call the name of an overloaded function template, the compiler will try to deduce its template arguments and check its explicitly declared template arguments. If successful, it will **instantiate a function template specialization**, then add this specialization to **the set of candidate functions used in overload resolution***

[when to perform substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_failure_is_not_an_error)

> *Specifically, when creating a candidate set for overload resolution, some (or all) candidates of that set may be the result of instantiated templates with (potentially deduced) template arguments substituted for the corresponding template parameters. If an error occurs during the substitution of a set of arguments for any given template, the compiler removes the potential overload from the candidate set instead of stopping with a compilation error, provided the substitution error is one the C++ standard grants such treatment*

I have not found the document about the order of substitution and instantiation

UPDATE:
the `deduction`,`substitution`(the sfinae is happened here) is parts of instantiation,however,except these,generate defination by substituting template arguments at the point of instantiation also a part of instantiation,when does it happen?after overload resolution or after the `substitution`(here is the sfinae)?

Comment: Substitution of template arguments for template parameters is part of the instantiation. It's not a separate process somehow.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik what about instantiate defination process,Does it occur after overload resolution or substitution or something others?

Comment: [overload_resolution doc](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution).

Comment: @Jarod42 thers are no details about the order of substitution and instantiated defination...

Comment: Of course instantiation happens first, then overload resolution. The compiler needs to know the signatures of candidate functions before it can pick the best-fitting one.

Comment: @ IgorTandetnik  Is it  the partical instantiation what you said about the instantiation,it only substitute template arguments for declartion and generate signatures ,What I said is the full instantiation,the complier will substitute template arguments for template paraments to generate the ordinary defination for the call at the point of instantiation

Comment: @IgorTandetnik  if your mean is full instantiation and the full instantiation was happened before overload resolution,whether the function template is the best match,the complier will all subustitute template aruguments into the defination and check the defination,maybe in the defination for one of these function templates ,exist a variable `typename T::type a = 0`,if the `T = int` ,it will obtain hard error ,actually ,it is not,In my understanding,the complier only instantiate the defination for the best match?

Comment: Ah, now I see what you are asking. The standard has this to say: "**[temp.inst]/7** If the function selected by overload resolution (16.3) can be determined without instantiating a class template definition, it is unspecified whether that instantiation actually takes place. **[temp.inst]/8** If a function template or a member function template specialization is used in a way that involves overload resolution, a declaration of the specialization is implicitly instantiated." So the compiler has to instantiate at least the declaration; and may or may not choose to also instantiate the definition.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik so,If a defination is necessary,the complier will instantiate the defination after `overload resolution`(found out the best match),Is it? The `deduction`,`substitution`(the sfinae is happened) and `generate defination for the specialization ` are all parts of instantiation,Is it?

Comment: Actually, I misread **[temp.inst]/7**. It talks about class template definition, relevant for member functions of class templates. The definition of a function template is definitely not instantiated unless and until the overload resolution selects it as best match; only the declaration is instantiated, as it's needed to participate in overload resolution. And yes, if instantiating the declaration fails, then this function template is simply ignored and not included in the overload set; that's the basis for SFINAE.

Comment: @IgorTandernik  so, the instantiation include `deduction` ,`substitution` and `generate defination`,thanks ,your answers is basicly what I want to understand

Answer (score 1):

Your example doesn't show much regarding your question as there is only one viable candidate: Substitution fails for `#1` as `int::type` is ill-formed, and thus there is only one function, `#2`.

On the other hand, it does mean that parameter substitution has to happen as part of the instantiation (as noted by @IgorTandetnik). And, for there to be any overloads to resolve, template instantiation has to happen before.

If you change `#1` to

```
template <typename T>
void test(T,T){}
```

you would have two viable overloads, and `#1` would be selected.

**Edit:**

On the other hand, if you change your main function to

```
struct {
   using type = int;
   int val = 0;
} x;

test(x,0);
```

both templates will be instantiated but overload resolution will fail as the two functions `void test(anonymous struct, int)` are ambiguous.

That also illustrates that the templates must be instantiated before overload resolution can take place.

Comment: @jackX I'm not quite sure what you mean by "instantiated definition", but does my edit make it clearer?

Comment: thanks,now I see substitution is a part of instantiation,but I also want to know when does the instantiated defination occur,Does it occur after substituting or overload resolution?

Comment: sorry,may be I have not express my question clearly,In my previous understanding,the instantiation only refer to generate defination for the specialization,now you correct me,the deduction and the substitution(here the sfinae is happened) are parts of instantiation,however, the complier need to genereate the defination  for specialization,when does it happened?Does it happen after searching for the best match or after substitution?

Comment: I still don't understand.  There is no specialization here, only overload resolution.

Comment: When the template is instantiated, the function is defined, not just declared.

Comment: no,the complier will generate ordinary defination by substituting template arguments at the point of instantiation except what you said

Comment: Is it the `partical instantiation` what you said about the instantiation,it only substitute template arguments for declartion and generate signatures

Comment: What I said is the full instantiation,if your mean is full instantiation and the full instantiation was happened before overload resolution,whether the function template is the best match,the complier will all subustitute template aruguments into the defination and check the defination,maybe in the defination for one of these function templates ,exist a variable `typename T::type a = 0`,if the `T = int `,it will obtain hard error ,actually ,it is not,In my understanding the complier only generate defination for the best match

Comment: I'm sorry, I thought you asked from a normal user's perspective. You may want to add the language-lawyer tag to make it clear that you are asking about the intricacies of the standard. (With that, I cannot help.)
You may also want to edit your question to make clear what the example code is intended to show.