# Some confusion about the point of instantiation of default argument used by function template

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer

For understanding this questions,please be sure to know the knowledge about the stateful meta programming,then we go.
Cite quotes about the point of instantiation of default arguments
[[temp.point]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.point#2)

> If a function template or member function of a class template is called in a way which uses the definition of a default argument of that function template or member function, the point of instantiation of the default argument is the point of instantiation of the function template or member function specialization.

If I understand correctly about the above quote,It means the POI of default argument is as the same as the POI of the function template that use the default argument(or if I misunderstand this bullet,please correct me).
Now,ready to consider below codes:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
template<int N>
struct state {
    friend auto call(state<N>);
};
template<int N>
struct add_state {
    friend auto call(state<N>) {
        return N;
    }
    static const int value = N;
};
template<typename T, int N>
T show(int = add_state<N>::value) {
    return T{};
}

int main() {
    show<int, 0>();
    call(state<0>{});
}
```

Actually,the above code is well-formed(the result here [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/tJEhMq)).However,accroding to the above quote, the POI of `add_state<0>` would be as the same as that of `show<int, 0>()`,the POI of `show<int, 0>()` either after `function main` or at the end of translate unit(Perhaps,most compliers take the end of translate unit as a POI for function template),However at that point,the call of `call(state<0>{});` could not find the definition of `call(state<0>{})` ,so it would be ill-formed.
the result of the above code proved that the POI of `add_state<0>` must  precede the call of `call(state<0>{})`,only under this situation,the definition of `call(state<0>{})` can be looked up.So it confuse me,How to interpret this question,I appreciate for  correct interpretaions.

Comment: I told it in your previous question dealing with stateful meta programing, I will repeat here. It is breaking so many things (like `std::is_same_v<S<>, S<>>` being `false`), it should proabaly considered ill-formed in general. See the question and its only answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44267673/is-stateful-metaprogramming-ill-formed-yet

Comment: @CygnusX1 thanks,I just want to understand the poni of instantiation about default argument within function template,However ,the result mentioned in my question is so confusion,It driver me want to know how the complier process such code,obviously,the complier seems to do not use the rules in standard to process such code,out of curios ,I want to know how complier process them

Comment: The point is, that it shouldn't matter how particular compilers implement their type system. The final values/types is what matters. But with stateful metaprogramming those internals come to light.

Comment: @CygnusX1  In other words,I want to konw that is it a defect in  standard about point of instantiation of  default argument or is it a compiler bug that standard does not sitpulation the implementation?