# Concise bidirectional static 1:1 mapping of values and types

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, template-meta-programming, c++20

I'm going to start with how I imagine using the code I'd like to create. It doesn't have to be exactly like this but it's a good example of what I mean by "concise" in the title. In my case it's mapping of a type to a related enumeration value.

```cpp
struct bar : foo<bar, foo_type::bar> { /* ... */ };
//               \_/  \___________/
//                ^ Type         ^ Value
```

What this should ideally do is an automatic registration of a bidirectional mapping between the first template parameter of `foo`, a type, and second, a value, just with the inheritance syntax and proper template parameters, so that I can later do what's in the example below.

```cpp
foo_type value = to_value<bar>; // Should be foo_type::bar
using type = to_type<foo_type::bar>; // Should be bar
```

I know I could manually write two template specializations per type-value pair to do this but I'm wondering if it could be less tedious than that without using macros.

What I tried already is...

1. Specializing template aliases to write less code to generate specializations. Apparently not possible in the current C++ version (17/20).
2. Specializing inherited template member types.

```cpp
struct foo_base
{
    template<typename T>
    struct to_value
    {};

    template<foo_type E>
    struct to_type
    {};
};

template<typename T, foo_type E>
struct foo : public foo_base
{
    template<>
    struct to_value<T>
    {
        static constexpr auto value = E;
    };

    template<>
    struct to_type<E>
    {
        using type = T;
    };
};
```

It would then be used similarily to what I presented at the beginning.

```cpp
foo_type value = foo_base::to_value<bar>::value; // Should be foo_type::bar
using type = foo_base::to_type<foo_type::bar>::type; // Should be bar
```

But it fails with errors below on MSVC.

> explicit specialization; 'foo_base::to_value' has already been instantiated
>
> 'foo_base::to_value': cannot specialize template in current scope

I feel like it might not be doable without explicit manual specializations, but C++17 allows a lot of surprising template based hacks, so want to confirm with more experienced people before I drop the idea.

Comment: what is `foo_type` ?

Comment: It's a scoped enum in my case. I added this detail in one of the edits.

Comment: `to_value` is easy: just make it look inside `bar` (you can add arbitrary symbols here in the `foo` wrapper).

Comment: Maybe friend functions would be of some use, they allow [creepy stuff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44267673/is-stateful-metaprogramming-ill-formed-yet).

Comment: There are going to be more derived types than just `bar` though.

Comment: Ah, that's not a problem actually if `value` is defined as a static member of templated `foo`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @yeputons said, friend-injection can help here. It's a spooky feature, and I can't say I fully understand how it works, but here it goes.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
struct tag {using type = T;};

template <typename T>
struct type_to_enum_friend_tag
{
    friend constexpr auto adl_type_to_enum(type_to_enum_friend_tag);
};
template <auto E>
struct enum_to_type_friend_tag
{
    friend constexpr auto adl_enum_to_type(enum_to_type_friend_tag);
};

namespace impl
{
    // Would've used `= delete;` here, but GCC doesn't like it.
    void adl_type_to_enum() {}
    void adl_enum_to_type() {}
}

template <typename T>
constexpr auto type_to_enum_helper()
{
    // Make sure our ADL works even if some stray
    // identifier named `adl_type_to_enum` is visible.
    using impl::adl_type_to_enum;
    return adl_type_to_enum(type_to_enum_friend_tag<T>{});
}
template <typename T>
inline constexpr auto type_to_enum = type_to_enum_helper<T>();

template <auto E>
constexpr auto enum_to_type_helper()
{
    // Make sure our ADL works even if some stray
    // identifier named `adl_type_to_enum` is visible.
    using impl::adl_enum_to_type;
    return adl_enum_to_type(enum_to_type_friend_tag<E>{});
}
template <auto E>
using enum_to_type = typename decltype(enum_to_type_helper<E>())::type;


template <typename T, auto E>
struct foo
{
    friend constexpr auto adl_type_to_enum(type_to_enum_friend_tag<T>)
    {
        return E;
    }
    friend constexpr auto adl_enum_to_type(enum_to_type_friend_tag<E>)
    {
        return tag<T>{};
    }
};

enum class foo_type {bar = 42};
struct bar : foo<bar, foo_type::bar>
{
    void say() {std::cout << "I'm bar!\n";}
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << int(type_to_enum<bar>) << '\n'; // 42
    enum_to_type<foo_type::bar>{}.say(); // I'm bar!
}
```

<kbd>[Run on gcc.godbolt.org](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAFlICsupVs1qhkAUgBMAISnTSAZ0ztkBPHUqZa6AMKpWAVwC2tQVvQAZPLUwA5YwCNMxEAHZJpAA6oFhdbT1DE0FvXzU6Kxt7IycXd0VlTFV/BgJmYgJA41NOBJVw2lT0gki7R2dBBTSMrODcquLS6NiuAEpFVANiZA4AcikAZmtkQywAanEBnXUq4kxmI0nscQAGAEFB4dHMCamCAE9PTAB9AmJmQgUl1Y31gkwjT2F73Z0Do9oFnYAVa/XZgyqMZpYATVzSAy%2BUTAw47SYAETGvwGslc8MmsnWN3uj2ecL2sM%2BRh%2BfzWAKB7xORGOWmMxyoxDw5lOzGAN3E4JuY25YwZTO0YzQtCqmAAHp5iGNmAYiFL0KxTrDTqgabRjBBKcrVXS%2BcyQa0Mey0Ya7g8nswXpMdNLZcsBst/mdAQQxrSjFrNbrtCy2VjOesebzGeZBXQReLJTbUHKFW6PbCIHHqZ7g979SaNsaUez1kTMApPMwemM8LijZi1oGAPRVsYAdU6rHQYF6ADcdpDMOgJgA2FYIsZYdj3Q19sYIZyYUhjBwysYAcR0OkHqHztBbLtYeAA1jtCAA6Lk81uoPDd5jyxVHLVuiCtMGo9EB4%2Bn8%2BXpMqyl3h8cp%2BZv/YmaeKvJSeZIqSQrhhKUoytGmrUnGE6sEcxB3uWR7cjWYwALLMLuYwKF0OydJKazwhYYwAO4kNuCiuu2tAllQBGoMSBFnMw%2BwYWMWFnloahUEykp5t24h9heCrwSqbpiSsJZ0a2eC%2BA47CHs%2B3KQtYoKlk8IAgBJV5UtJaqLNm6ljHMBBdIxBlSdqRgakqCEmfSqboD6VrIssnJogaZn/oBuIWvibyEl84H2jc1hbjYobCvcEYwbKdlursiIpS5SEoZ5Sxof5gXmpaUxRmMdoOmskEJdBJUfoZxxZc4aF%2BhW1a1rh%2BGEXMYwkWMZEUdRxC0fRWhMSxbGzJx3G8Vg9B4IJzhjCJvYrLZTnGcYsnyWMinKap3GadCOmsHpBm1ZSGaBpZ1kxvZ8ZHImLnJkqXruSCVplRyj5%2BRWv4FcBVolR96wHaCZ2wmlMIfOFWAjF%2BYPXg1xDvblrStHp535VippBUVoVQ2x3zToDpLki6NCoOh5kvXFUGRrBN0ZeqjPui9HlTF5BrmZ93GXZgVnEIxdotTyv1U25NNVXTsqnY9n4JvDJys29UxlZzlYi/66uBtyV0C8CrI5ZFPnov5gaiwFmNrKlIzMAodHk4ZD4OOkEPcJIv3%2BaTM4uyAvKoBTUzO2Qfty0celB6S3PmSeZ4EZx36fVU6B6Wgc5WlaEySJIACSLZGN7xBgGA4gAKw6LQUju9mxp%2BibP3rNYLpGBctBNZmwvcknKedC66dTCW9COdezkbYH6RLPeffLi2pflzPKI8bWbvcQrVoO5S4fj0bj77go8ffYvYy570%2BdB0XRp/r07THb0Je9KQpi9Cs9%2BoCAvQ6HIcgsV0xaDJw98EDfs/VGpBtwgBLpIfcnBXAlxWH2AAnAADh7AMFYiCS65Bvtwe%2Bj9n6kFfr0e%2BCgQArFIIAp%2BV9SBwFgDARAKBWKeDwOwMgFAIBoEeEwioNtRCcBWHw0gglWD3GIMQiADggH3wcNYdI%2Bw37/1IOw4k9AADytBWCyIoaQLAzdRDsAkVovAcxkjtmIZosUSQZR9DwY3ZQ%2BitwOHOMQfYegsByIAYyIwbj2g0HoEwNgHBOADH4CADwwhRAoE/jIIQeAHDEMgO0VAngCimIALRJwRBIGQchJDMDGCkusbBWB5LrGKDieSjjoBEGoZAKTnDEBIAoIhiRkgaAerofQ2QzDaCaOUFwuRQh%2BDoLUHIXgfCDNoD0mIFR6jNIKEUGoHS6h5CSHM6oJRrBlCmX0xQazhmVDWZMlonB2gKBIj0NoQg353wfvoghopkEpJ7NwQUYTQS8P3CsD5YwIC4EICQTOAxchjD0Bw5hALJD3g/lkmQACJEgInBeCod5QEgG4CXD53AViSFcE8gYAwS6AvgfAy5vRsGkE8bAm5miCFEJIWQuFVDaEQCQD3TwMpyCUHYYw5hITSBdj%2BdsnxjAWB6N4aQSi5xPBeJJdc3BL836DEkFRQgCAxj3J7I8553C3mfN1bCih8L5hYBcMirB98KWkLlfgt%2BtLSHkOAe0MB3BXD7kQZIbg8CBjwJWIEns8DOAlxJQMHBtybX0oNdfN%2BkgQ3UrDfaq%2B7R2wiP8KioAA%3D%3D%3D)</kbd>

It appears to work on both GCC, Clang, and MSVC.

I'm using an `auto` template parameter, so you can map different types to constants from different enums, or even to plain integers. Constraining this to accept only a single specific enum should be easy, and is left as an exercise to the reader.

---

Of course, for the type-to-enum mapping you could simply add a `static constexpr` member variable to `foo`. But I don't know any good alternatives to friend-injection for the enum-to-type mapping.

Comment: Is not it an exploit of core language issue [#2118](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_active.html#2118)?

Comment: @Oliv Yep, this is what CWG 2118 is about. As of now, the standard seems to say that it's well-formed. CWG said [they don't like](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44268181/2752075) this feature, but they can say anything they want. :P I doubt they'll find a way (or dare) to remove it from the language without breaking some well-behaved programs.

Comment: For stateful template metaprogramming, this is somewhat tame and thus more reliable, compared to things like [unconstexpr](https://github.com/DaemonSnake/unconstexpr) (which only worked for a single specific version of GCC).

Answer (score 4):

@HolyBlackCat's answer is fantastic. Type-to-enum can be achieved in simpler ways than ADL hackery, so I tried to distil the enum-to-type bit to the bare minimum:

```
template <auto E>
struct adl_to_type 
{
    friend auto foo_type_to_type(adl_to_type);
};

template<typename T, foo_type E>
struct foo 
{
    friend auto foo_type_to_type(adl_to_type<E>) { return (T*)nullptr; };
};

template <foo_type E>
using to_type = std::remove_pointer_t<decltype(foo_type_to_type(adl_to_type<E>{}))>;

int main() 
{
    to_type<foo_type::bar>{}.say();
    return 0; 
}
```

<kbd>[Run on gcc.godbolt.org](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAFlICsupVs1qhkAUgBMAISnTSAZ0ztkBPHUqZa6AMKpWAVwC2tEJMmkt6ADJ5amAHLGARpmJmLAB1QLC62nqGJh6k3r5qdLb2Tkau7uaKypiq/gwEzMQEgcamCUoqEbRpGQRRji5uIQrpmdnBeTWlduWxleYAlIqoBsTIHADkUgDMdsiGWADU4kM6BACenpgA%2BgTEzIQK09jiAAwAgsOj45hTM%2BrVxJjMRlu7B/taxhNjzAoKEzSoKwsnd%2BIA7LJ9hMQRNnBlSHdQRMFJ5rpD9gCACLTIH3PYETBGTzCTGnHTMAxECbbIbbfYXAyqCbMdCsFZfeaLKaIwFQ0FUYh4Kw0omoD6oRk/BnfRYQWn0oiizDtVF/f4ooZou6Y7G4zDTWY/WjXE4AFVIAqFzNJ5L2lOpnxZBzZwI5XJ5hOJn2lIqZmHFdLdP01pvaU0BE0uBB6tAmED1ACp2rQDKxWJ5VqiA4rlQq5Yj9qqccw8ZqXe6Sbd9gZfKIJlLC9MkTCCOgQCBLkZUAA3ZbeOyY4grTVYMbu6iC12Vn6eyXGjUzU0A2QK9qyskZ9EWghgjITEBGzXgshG6UNndba0z9kgluoPDoGHMOYQf0z6r1lDdVeazVTcwASTA/SMa%2BIYBgOIACsOi0FIkhyumrKpn8FKrFSq6wtcG5bjMyFGIaBY/A2GFHvKaLQuel7Xre96Ao%2BDZoES%2BLvhB36/jCcJGIBIFgRBUEojBS53J2ExGOstB3gRp4VhO%2BZDu6B4ZLcbIKgAdAoN7CUqokjosEkTrhzGybOSKKcpC6EaCwahhMOw8Qq/SdKwID9MB/SkKY/Q7I5qB2TochyDC3S9L8khDJwjkEHZrnzqQADWIDAZI8mcP8wE7AAbDsACcAAcSVDDs6XAZwQh2dwjnOa5pDuf0jkKCAOykCFLnWaQcCwDAiDPtieDsGQFAQGg7WdSgwiiJwOwjaQVAdV2VUQM4oWOc4dgZHMdlBaQvVGFoBAAPK0KwS31aQWACaI7CzQdeCXCkbZVftmAAB7JESAylZ2yinaweDOGsxBzHoWDLcFXJGP9nQ0PQTBsBwnBDPwZhCCIYheTIQgfVVkCdKgib%2BNdAC0j7VhIMhyJIzATNjADqbCsKTZN3asJPY4s6AiGoyDY24xAkAolVJCkGgQFYdSmPlVhlDEcSCGEfh0ILEs%2BFLtCixU7j5fkySFMUtT6Dkgiq7zRSNIrrTK4ojQyyrBvNGLlScJ0Ci%2BX0XA2XZDlOad5W3Zl2NJdwzyDcAEzDfJOxB%2BGuCECQH6BYaeh9W4keSP6nmEzIwWzeFCBXFg7h3pFIDcMBQfcDskj/N7QxDMBgWpalBX9EVpBA4lrv7eVlXVbVaeNS1EBIC%2BnhEuQlC9Z4HVtJY%2BBEMboOMCwJ3DaQADuayeMDtcuyVbl2cMkgTAvhAIBMHtJV7PsvOWgfB6VdVhZ0Ge0pUOe2XXjmNzVG9lXZbc1df1mdFF3D/HkulSQ3BUpDFSjsKGSVUqcGArXIYxU3afw7vVcKT9JCIJbsgn%2B4U2zEF8BobgQA)</kbd>

It still blows my mind. The `auto` return type is absolutely crucial here. Even changing it to `T*` in `foo` will yield a compile error. I also tried with getting rid of `adl_to_type` and using `integral_constant` instead, but it seems that declaring `foo_type_to_type` as the friend function *inside* the type used to resolve ADL is the key here.

Comment: The extra ADL hackery is needed to prevent ADL from breaking if user does something like `namespace A {int foo_type_to_type;} using namespace A;`. An unlikely scenario, but I wouldn't want to debug this sorcery if it ever breaks. :)