# Constructor for any initializer_list accepted by given T

Tags: c++, generics, constructor, initializer-list

I am looking for a solution to create constructor accepting all `std::initializer_list`s accepted by given `T`. For example:

```
#include <initializer_list>
#include <utility>

template <typename T> struct AllInits
{
  AllInits(std::initializer_list<?>){}
};

struct ManyListTypes
{
  ManyListTypes(std::initializer_list<bool>){}
  ManyListTypes(std::initializer_list<int>){}
  ManyListTypes(std::initializer_list<std::pair<int, int>>){}
};

int main()
{
  AllInits<ManyListTypes> first{true,false,true};
  AllInits<ManyListTypes> second{1,2,3};
  AllInits<ManyListTypes> third{{1,1},{2,2},{3,3}};
  return 0;
}
```

Is it even possible?

Comment: `template <typename U> AllInits(std::initializer_list<U>)`?

Comment: @S.M. Doesn't work for the last example.

Comment: I was thinking about some `std::tuple` but `{1, 1}` is not detected as `std::tuple<int,int>`. Any ideas?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat of cause it will not work without suitable overloads.

Comment: @wehin19066 `{1, 1}` is `std::initializer_list<int>`, not `std::tuple<int,int>`.

Comment: @S.M.: `{1, 1}` has no type.

Comment: What about `{ 1, "abc" }`?

Comment: @Jarod42 so it seems there is no generic solution for this?

Comment: @RemyLebeau This won't let you pass any braced-init-lists to it.

Comment: @RemyLebeau could you please provide some code example?

Comment: There is no reflection in C++. So I doubt we can retrieve possible argument without help. if `ManyListTypes` provide a `using arg_types = std::tuple<bool, int, std::pair<int, int>>`, we might change `AllInits` accordly.

Comment: @Jarod42 `If {1, 1}` has no type, what type of a is here: `#include <initializer_list>

int main() {
  auto a = {1, 1};
  int b = a;
  return 0;
}`

Comment: @S.M. `a` is `std::initializer_list<int>`, but `{1, 1}` is not. `auto` has special rules for this case. Try `decltype` on it...

Comment: @HolyBlackCat `{1, 1}` is not an expression, `decltype` does not work in a such way.

Comment: @S.M. Since it's not an expression, it can't have a type. Q.E.D. :P

Comment: @S.M.: From [list_initialization#Notes](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization#Notes) *"A braced-init-list is not an expression and therefore has no type, e.g. `decltype({1,2})` is ill-formed."* and *"A special exception is made for [type deduction using the keyword `auto`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction#Other_contexts) , which deduces any braced-init-list as `std::initializer_list` in copy-list-initialization."*

Comment: Can you use specify types by hands? `template <typename T, typename U>                                              
struct AllInits                                                                
{                                                                              
  AllInits(std::initializer_list<U>){}                                         
};  AllInits<ManyListTypes, bool> first{true,false,true};                        
  AllInits<ManyListTypes, int> second{1,2,3};                                  
  AllInits<ManyListTypes, std::pair<int, int>> third{{1,1},{2,2},{3,3}}; `

Comment: @wehin19066: Is inheriting constructor an option `template <typename T> struct AllInits : T { using T::T; };`?

Comment: @Jarod42 Only if it would help in some way

Comment: @wehin19066 It solves your problem, but forces `AllInits<ManyListTypes>` to inherit from `ManyListTypes`.

Comment: Could you please provide some example?

Answer (score 1):

The best practical solution would be:

```
template <typename T>
struct AllInits
{
    template <typename U>
    requires std::constructible_from<T, std::initializer_list<U> &>
    AllInits(std::initializer_list<U>){}
};
```

This passes the first two testcases, but fails the third one. I.e. you can't have nested braced lists.

A possible workaround is to specify the element types:

```
AllInits<ManyListTypes> third{std::pair{1,1}, std::pair{2,2}, std::pair{3,3}};
```

---

There is a solution that doesn't have this limitation, but it relies on some arcane tricks, and probably shouldn't be used in practice.

<kbd>[Run on gcc.godbolt.org](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGIMwDspK4AMngMmAByPgBGmMQgAMykAA6oCoRODB7evv5BaRmOAmER0SxxCcl2mA5ZQgRMxAQ5Pn6Btpj2xQwNTQSlUbHxSbaNza15HQrjA%2BFDFSOJAJS2qF7EyOwc5onhyN5YANQmiW5oDFspBAqn2CYaAIK7%2B4eYJ2fIM%2BhYVHcPzzMe0ubw%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%2BJuyYy12r2KgsswGg6ryuECqKlrysq6rasweq4UaowWquxIZrmvqBqW9aVrG1AUnx1x2LNPsB3cgMRy8jVxz8gKgrw5twsi1QgrHUVzzELxMGimMjkB3blwVYg0uYh7XGehhXtLd6iC%2B7TdMBgGDOBlLZbOfzAqOCKsFUO5SpMc08QIDYGCNE0sSF7xRanEz6at71OPBtzHikzzyW8tmjf5oPRTkBg8AARxFzmKyrbnY1N4sPldDRQ9Z0VTldNT0DFw1ykBhQjhAYKqxXTBgGIMRsZexpBCxLmwoIILk/NpljKsL0uMZ6TRzD94Q4dAejgj6PY7L0LayT3n89jQuDMZNwh7HmPMFb3mgqwA5HQgTTNd%2B7XAb11LDY5k3Z7drvnVWI5c43MHsBLyeK6rmulMMAhG/jqeaRbo4F6KiXivSOa8N5m2sFwIKuc7hVmnMLV2T8rbXx7n7Y6qpA6Z0HufAW7xnYiznhLAyEUlDNHiM/SW0tT7L3PoAlgwDz74MQXAhBQUmF3DjiFaMf94yd09qg8yHhlbRgcCQGGCo6gCFcoOJmGCzi4LdFOJ4epxaPAYBSCKhBdJywhlaf2zMiK6LTMPLBo9SDMTTAo7Ok9GBMBiPQOE7FaTfxCkiOEChxxwmnFiOQnDy6R0cFCWExAES/UwbY8OLCXa0njP8KcTJzFGMsSPaxeFbH2JpE4r%2BZxAYkPiDLLEWoM4RPeHIKJIsYnUlgSAeBLtCQ7iUXdI4lN4i5jEXIIySkpopiSdaG2ds%2BHdx9jubu3sGZoNkf3UxRSTElNTnfOcedGkqMNM6TAEiWhEClIMj2CkJl9xZnMyczJHgrNjGsjZwYSBLxmdvWgu8tQQDURogJ2izjHOQZ7W%2B99liPx2ag/RcjgwjzXNSYpPkQKEMBrpEIqAkr/J9jIg54SfIzKbtPI47ZIXLJEbGaFv1YVJUKX4kA4QzbuMwGvS4rs3AgXbHEk5nyjHCVGkpYsqtQUJjCfIkedzd77x%2BjMI%2ButEr62JSbf47tflVkdPSju4paCSiMp80ZTTbThGALM%2BZfL1wKqVb8riQzxmAqmUcqFBldIUItQSuF4q8LdQANaZN5hSqlWwsR0JuVvWo9z1wXNqJs65hTJXX2gYsh%2B1TakEPiUg92AjBQUX4tXRw9oeqOiOElQgCAHTimzF4Qgdj6BKzOdc6RvcA48umYQoQGr6BXNlluZiNajB1q2cquNRjm3AFbSQCAeEISBMRME0JyJ3kW3%2BWM30%2ByK3AumeC8chCjxiUcPWgF6DTWovnaKdskYcUxVjEu%2B5eBV3vKCpyt5bhlByvuB3UuXae0G0vXceljajHqvtPezAJ6n1MirJ%2B%2BtcrxlpnfZq2ShEXRxmpBeq94Y4npStMxE1hyfJyHqX0yl%2Ba8TFzwkpfdeAMlwjOiKO1P8B1LSHfCMDPi7io0aWmQ9K6239oCeRhsISqNnFQ0ybsHbPS7N9uZLUua4ZiFmWW6dBjK1mr3eLP8qBPqlwY8erZ4qFH4tHcBapjpeQ9LVXaTVSnv0zLU9ajTxyZWxN/SAQzKnEVGqneZNZLBUDibOUcI8hgKS6U5bcV9TSPPqO8/GBQfbSMsaCZR7lbgYjydoBbFVXt/OeaC9SELzHIQUfY1Flc8XeP0eS79HzoXXHhcyyO7Jbg8IpHpI%2BlcQUcsxp4ygydeyVxHG6uEDcOimlLhXJyrEcnUBYgC15wrwXqkcewF1/sZlBTnqizFzw9XBAkuq3gWrK30wNxjVOtMg3hsFZmD5mjNApRf3NNwvgYglCkG4fw4Z1p9tnBGylzAjIn5KAuHnc0UCzCkESPd%2BDRwntuBe2N1LNGCAIHW99ruFgoFcE9uY80f2zBI%2BQckAH3d7O9g4KsWgnAEK8D8BwLQpBUCcDcNYaw2Z1ibDJECHgt3NB49WA6kAkgzDSkkAEDQiRJCJAAJxmB5wADkFxoBCZV9CcEkMTln5POC8AUCAdOBAWerDgLAGAiB8JKjoPEcglA0D6/oAkYAXBLd8DoDLFXEAYgK5iOEJoFJOBM5N2wQQYEGC0Fd6T3gWBuotu2GT/AeI6jTjewr4stROQh94BXAn/v9D4ersQCkHgsBu94LiPALBs%2BrCoAYYACg9ZgQ1NnmQggRBiHYFIKv8glBqAV7oKBBgjAoGp5YFPMQVeQFWJTHoKuODiW%2BNnUwlhrBmA0EcPaYhaCz92sWOks/qToE/oJcS8RiDXNn2BRIyuugBqyC4fckw/BQNCPMcolQ9CFEyAIc/d/0gP4YIMG/IwoE1Ekb0WYT%2Bv9H4/59DNDv7DAJBf5/6eBtB6A5ggHX5gESCrAKB05bB6C4iYDbA8D46E7y7J4U4cCqCi5lTiRlSSBHDADID5iW7ShcBHAQBU6T7d4Sz4BbIsSJBQJHAeCm7kK7BcDLA54a5s5JAITSiJDsFcAIQISC4BBmCBCi4SHSBJ5y6kD54ITpwk5k74HK6q7M7%2B6a464QBIAETjQtwUAQAm4pAG7gHBAsEkB6D8DV6iDiD14OGN4qDqDJ5JTVwpAF4y4cBE6kAaG8D4FgScgmHNLQyEHEGkHkGUFHDUG0H0EiiWFm5sF8ECF6GrDiiaQjAbh%2BHKGqHqEK5aG2A6Hq6ZGkDs5cCC7SgBCSBlRlQBDVES6JDyGC6SAIR%2BEH6BHFFK66FaD6HwBa664WFWFG7mHJFWEoDt4W6JAaDpw0D3LxB24O7J5O7MDp6V4e6MAEDe6%2B4K6B5NTiDJ5h7H6R7D5k4x7IBx4K6J4K6IgxBp4Z4YCYE57Lj57cB458DF6l6irl6MCV6uE17OHSCuGKDuEt7%2BD6BNSd6ME2APF955GD5ZDD6j4Vjj5d4WDT6L7z6L7L7Vyr6Ywb7IBb7EA77bLiT76H7dAn4QCuD/7BD7igGLDWH349AMlslZDMm34AE0kCDAEtBQF5C8nH78mzDcmf5jD9AMmwFzBlAIF8FrAbCoFQLoGvHYH%2BG4GaGcBREkFkE4yapcCJDSgaAml0EMFWBMG4CEBiK8FBRcEpE8FAhmD8H9Gs6kDZFYAJB5Hs5iHSjT51GSCi4BCi4IQBAyEhn5G8CFE9F4F9Eq5q4a6kDDGGEgDGGcjjGjFm5QmYw2nWFAlOF16gmyDgnN6eHeG%2BFJ4BFBGK4cChEEDhGthHC6kxEGnxHGmmkz5JHcFli7AukZEDFZH4hemUAakFEgBqGxnakcDaGJkVFVE1FcCi6S5Gli5C4aAi7S5J7dE1klHlEDHJkGEGFIBZmG5mGnkJDTjIApApBeLVEIgjgzBwiqCkHW5LFSiUCrFk7rEu5bEiie67E%2B5%2B6h6KhHHx6kCnER5R7J5XE3HJ53HJ4PFPGZ6vG3bvG%2BFF4mi/HJT/Ek5M4Fm14SDFmCClkeFk66DJAzGwmWnwn4aIkD7XAomcB8j3gT40WBgzDUmil%2BB0ln5CkX6MnoASmskv7sn8XP5FBcnwEskwGAE9ACkylyX1DinSU8lSkTDiUQH9DCWIFKn05oF4jql%2BHVm9EEExH0JXl3zVHSgcWxj0GYlBTWmsF2mcGTGpG7ArADnumem5FCGyEml1FSAIRSDSG84BCC5RkqETlFFxkzmlFzkHkplGFhEZnnluVLA2F5n2GyDAlFkN6kUK5eFMA%2BGfEakmWxX1mNmRHmUKCWXTjWW2XmnpW9lAieVum/IenDm%2BWRUxm7nxllGCGVESCi7ShlQbk84aBjWkGtEBCvnblanBF9H7nulJ5mALW1leUdWR5Sgn6SBAA%3D%3D%3D)</kbd>

```
#include <concepts>
#include <cstddef>
#include <initializer_list>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

// Some helpers.

template <typename T>
struct Tag
{
    using type = T;
};

template <typename ...P>
struct TypeList
{
    inline static constexpr std::size_t size = sizeof...(P);
};

template <typename T>
void PrintType()
{
    #ifndef _MSC_VER
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n';
    #else
    std::cout << __FUNCSIG__ << '\n';
    #endif
};

// A generic stateful-template list.

constexpr void adl_ListElem() {} // A dummy ADL target.

template <typename Key, std::size_t Index>
struct ElemViewer
{
    #if defined(__GNUC__) && !defined(__clang__)
    #pragma GCC diagnostic push
    #pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wnon-template-friend"
    #endif
    friend constexpr auto adl_ListElem(ElemViewer);
    #if defined(__GNUC__) && !defined(__clang__)
    #pragma GCC diagnostic pop
    #endif
};

template <typename Key, std::size_t Index, typename Value>
struct ElemWriter
{
    friend constexpr auto adl_ListElem(ElemViewer<Key, Index>) {return Tag<Value>{};}
};

template <typename Key, typename Unique, std::size_t Index = 0, typename = void>
struct NumElems : std::integral_constant<std::size_t, Index> {};

template <typename Key, typename Unique, std::size_t Index>
struct NumElems<Key, Unique, Index, decltype(adl_ListElem(ElemViewer<Key, Index>{}), void())> : std::integral_constant<std::size_t, NumElems<Key, Unique, Index+1, void>::value> {};

template <typename Key, typename Value>
struct ElemInserter : ElemWriter<Key, NumElems<Key, Value>::value, Value>, std::true_type {};

// Constructor detection.

template <typename T>
struct AnyInitList
{
    template <
        typename U,
        typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<U, std::initializer_list<typename U::value_type>>>,
        typename = std::enable_if_t<ElemInserter<T, typename U::value_type>::value>
    >
    operator U() const
    {
        return {};
    }
};

template <typename T, typename = void>
struct DetectCtors {};

template <typename T>
struct DetectCtors<T, decltype(T(AnyInitList<T>{}), void())> {};

template <typename Type, typename I>
struct ElemListLow {};

template <typename T, std::size_t ...I>
struct ElemListLow<T, std::index_sequence<I...>>
{
    static constexpr TypeList<typename decltype(adl_ListElem(ElemViewer<T, I>{}))::type...> helper() {}
    using type = decltype(helper());
};

template <typename T>
struct ElemList : ElemListLow<T, std::make_index_sequence<NumElems<T, decltype(DetectCtors<T>{}, void())>::value>> {};

// Generating a type with the suitable constructors.

template <typename T>
struct SingleCtor
{
    SingleCtor() {}
    SingleCtor(std::initializer_list<T>) {}
};

template <typename T, typename>
struct MultiCtor;

template <typename T, typename ...P>
struct MultiCtor<T, TypeList<P...>> : SingleCtor<P>...
{
    using SingleCtor<P>::SingleCtor...;

    using list = TypeList<P...>;
    
    template <typename U>
    requires std::constructible_from<T, std::initializer_list<U> &>
    MultiCtor(std::initializer_list<U>){}
};

// The final type.

template <typename T>
struct Foo : MultiCtor<T, typename ElemList<T>::type>
{
    using MultiCtor<T, typename ElemList<T>::type>::MultiCtor;
};

// Demo.

struct ManyListTypes
{
    ManyListTypes(std::initializer_list<bool>){}
    ManyListTypes(std::initializer_list<int>){}
    ManyListTypes(std::initializer_list<std::pair<int, int>>){}
};

int main()
{
    PrintType<Foo<ManyListTypes>::list>(); // TypeList<bool, int, std::pair<int, int>>

    Foo<ManyListTypes> first{true,false,true};
    Foo<ManyListTypes> second{1,2,3};
    Foo<ManyListTypes> third{{1,1},{2,2},{3,3}};
}
```

There is a lot going on here.

- `class AnyInitList` has a templated conversion operator to `std::initializer_list<??>`.
- An attempt is made to construct your type (`ManyListTypes`) from `AnyInitList`, but we don't care if it succeeds, any errors are hidden by SFINAE.
- This process instantiates `AnyInitList` for all types that the constructors of `ManyListTypes` can accept. We then use stateful metaprogramming to collect those types into a list.
- The rest is easy. We create `class SingleCtor<T>` that's constructible from `std::initializer_list<T>`, then inherit the final type from several specializations of `SingleCtor` (inheriting constructors), one per type in the list we got.

Comment: *"it relies on some arcane tricks, and probably shouldn't be used in practice."* See [is-stateful-metaprogramming-ill-formed-yet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44267673/is-stateful-metaprogramming-ill-formed-yet)