# Behaviour of friend function template returning deduced dependent type in class template

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, c++20

I've happened across the following code, the behaviour of which is diagreed upon by all of GCC, Clang, and MSVC:

```
#include <concepts>

template<typename T>
auto foo(T);

template<typename U>
struct S {
    template<typename T>
    friend auto foo(T) {
        return U{};
    }
};

S<double> s;
static_assert(std::same_as<decltype(foo(42)), double>);
```

Live demo: https://godbolt.org/z/hK6xhesKM

`foo()` is declared at global namespace with deduced return type. `S<U>` provides a definition for `foo()` via a friend function, where it returns a value of type `U`.

What I expected is that when `S` is instantiated with `U=double`, its definition of `foo()` gets put in the global namespace and `U` is substituted in, due to how friend functions work, effectively like this:

```
template<typename T>
auto foo(T);

S<double> s;

template<typename T>
auto foo(T) {
    return double{};
}
```

Thus I expect `foo()`'s return type is `double`, and the following static assertion should pass:

```
static_assert(std::same_as<decltype(foo(42)), double>);
```

However, what actually happens is that all three compilers disagree on the behaviour.

GCC passes the static assertion, like I expect.

Clang fails the static assertion, as it seems to believe that `foo()` returns `int`:

> 'std::is_same_v<int, double>' evaluated to false

And MSVC produces a different error entirely:

> 'U': undeclared identifier

I find it bizarre that all the compilers have different behaviour here for a seemingly simple code example.
The issue does not occur if `foo()` isn't templated ([see demo here](https://godbolt.org/z/vPezPM6P5)), or if it doesn't have deduced return type ([see demo here](https://godbolt.org/z/445zzrx8v)).

**Which compiler has the correct behaviour? Or, is the code ill-formed NDR or undefined behaviour? (And, why?)**

Comment: The code looks legal, I believe Clang & MSVC are bugged.

Comment: Why declaring `foo()` at global namespace, here?

Comment: @TheDreamsWind Because `foo(42)` will not find it without that declaration. The `friend` declaration will only be found by ADL.

Comment: Isn't that [CWG 2118](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#2118) aka [stateful metaprogramming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44267673/is-stateful-metaprogramming-ill-formed-yet) aka the [C++ type loophole](https://alexpolt.github.io/type-loophole.html)? If yes, at some point this should become ill-formed, but apparently is [currently legal although buggy in practice](https://b.atch.se/).

Comment: @Sedenion Funnily enough I did come across this code while experimenting with the stateful metaprogramming thing. However I do believe this particular code example should be well-formed either way.

Comment: @MCΔT Indeed, your program is well-formed, as long as you ever only instantiate (implicitly or explicitly) a single instantiation of `S` (ignoring specializing `S` to remove the friend).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Which compiler has the correct behaviour? Or, is the code ill-formed NDR or undefined behaviour? (And, why?)

As @Sedenion points out in a comment, whilst touching upon the domain of [CWG 2118](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#2118) (we'll return to this further down) this program is by the current standard well-formed and GCC is correct to accept it, whereas Clang and MSVC are incorrect to reject it, as governed by [[dcl.spec.auto.general]/12](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/dcl.spec.auto.general#12) and [/13](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/dcl.spec.auto.general#13) [**emphasis** mine]:

> **/12** Return type deduction for a templated entity that is a function or function template with a placeholder in its declared type
> **occurs when the definition is instantiated** even if the function body contains a return statement with a non-type-dependent operand.
>
> **/13** Redeclarations or specializations of a function or function template
> with a declared return type that uses a placeholder type **shall also
> use that placeholder, not a deduced type**. Similarly, redeclarations or
> specializations of a function or function template with a declared
> return type that does not use a placeholder type shall not use a
> placeholder.
>
> [Example 6:
>
> ```
> auto f();
> auto f() { return 42; }            // return type is int
> auto f();                          // OK
> // ...
> template <typename T> struct A {
>   friend T frf(T);
> };
> auto frf(int i) { return i; }      // not a friend of A<int>
> ```

Particularly the "not a friend of `A<int>`" example of /13 highlights that the redeclaration shall use a placeholder type (`frf(T)`, and not a deduced type (`frf(int)`), whereas *otherwise* that particular example would be valid.

/12, along with [[temp.inst]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/temp.inst#3) (below) covers the that return type deduction for the friend occurs only after the friend's primary template definition has been made available (formally: it's declaration but not definition has been instantiated) from the instantiation of the `S<double>` enclosing class template specialization.

> The implicit instantiation of a class template specialization causes
>
> - (3.1) **the implicit instantiation of the declarations, but not of the definitions**, of the non-deleted class member functions, member
>   classes, scoped member enumerations, static data members, member
>   templates, and **friends**; and
> - [...]
>
> However, for the purpose of determining whether an instantiated
> redeclaration is valid according to [basic.def.odr] and [class.mem], a
> declaration that corresponds to a definition in the template is
> considered to be a definition.
>
> [Example 4:
>
> ```
> // ...
>
> template<typename T> struct Friendly {
>   template<typename U> friend int f(U) { return sizeof(T); }
> };
> Friendly<char> fc;
> Friendly<float> ff;  // error: produces second definition of f(U)
> ```
>
> — end example]

---

#### CWG 2118: Stateful metaprogramming via friend injection

As covered in detail e.g. in [A foliage of folly](https://dfrib.github.io/a-foliage-of-folly/), one can rely on the single first instantiation of a class template to control how the definition of a friend looks like. *First* here means essentially relying on meta-programming state to specify this definition.

In OP's example the first instantiation, `S<double>`, is used to set the definition of the primary template of the friend `foo` such that its deduced type will always deduce to `double`, for all specializations of the friend. If we ever (in the whole program) instantiate, implicitly or explicitly, a second instantiation of `S` (ignoring `S` being specialized to remove the friend), we run into ODR-violations and undefined behavior. This means that this kind of program is, in practice, essentially useless, as it would serve clients undefined behavior on a platter, but as covered in the article linked to above it can be used for utility classes to [circumvent private access rules](https://github.com/dfrib/accessprivate) (whilst still being entirely well-formed) or other hacky mechanisms such as stateful metaprogramming (which typically runs into or beyond the grey area of well-formed).